# Only display ToolStripMenuItem icons

Tags: winforms, toolstrip, toolstripitem

I have a Windows Forms ToolStripSplitButton which shows only an icon.  I have added some ToolStripMenuItems and I have set their DisplayStyle to ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image.  The drop down display the area for text (but it's blank), and the image to the left of the empty text area.  Is there a way to get rid of the text area so it only displays the icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set these properties on the DropDown of the ToolStripSplitButton:

```
toolStripSplitButton1.DropDown.AutoSize = false;
toolStripSplitButton1.DropDown.Width = 27; // Or whatever size your icon width is.
```